# Stub .push method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stubbing

I have some code that uses `.push`.
I want to write a unit test that tests the failure scenario of this code, but i can't figure out the syntax.

My code looks like this

```
   if object.groups.push(group)
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t(".success")
  else
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t(".failure")
  end
```

I've tried to stub out the `.push` method so it returns false, but it still returns true.

My stubbing attempts are below:

```
      object.groups.should_receive(:push).with(group).and_return(false)
  allow(object.groups).to receive(:push).with(group).and_call_original
```

Am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is `object`? What is `object.groups`? Are you sure that the code and the spec are actually referencing the same things?

Comment: In order to confidently answer your question, I'd need to see a [mcve], not just these code snippets out of context. What are you actually testing? How does this test work? There might be a better approach, but I'm not sure what to suggest without more information.

Comment: This question is just plain strange as the only `#push` method in Ruby is `Array#push` and it always returns `self` and an array is truthy. Thus the else condition will never run.

Comment: This is really an odd test. Do you mean to test if `group` exists before pushing?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to stub this. It should either be a controller test, where you have access to the request and can check the response body for the status or you could add a integration test to check if the success UI is displayed.